Datagrid basic question regarding Hierarchy View
I would like to ask a question regarding DataGrid Master Detail Hierarchy.
Assuming I have a model like below:
Class A 
{
   List<B> {get; set;}
   string abv {get; set;}
}

Class B 
{
List<C> {get; set;}
}

Class C
{
string abc {get; set;}
}


Now, I can show detail hierarchy grid like below and it works:
<RadzenDataGrid 
              Data="@AListModel"
              TItem="A">
    <Template Context="BModel">
        <RadzenDataGrid 
                        Data="@B.C"
                        TItem="C">
            <Columns>
                <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="C"
                                      Property="abc"
                                      Title="Test" >
                </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            </Columns>
        </RadzenDataGrid>
    </Template>
    <Columns>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="A" Property="abv " Title="Test" Width="80px" />
    </Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>


Now this will show A with nested C inside. How can I reverse this same grid ? By showing all A's (parent) inside of C's (child) using the same model ? So I want to C's to be main row and then A's inside expandable.
Reverse order of Hierarchy
